# Save Form from another Action

Tags: php, symfony

I have Two Action, GetAllPost and newComment
I have a page with many Post and each Post have commentForm

PostController

```
public function getPostAction () {
     return array(
    );
}
```

Twig

```
{% for post in app.user.posts %}
        <p>{{ post.id }} - {{ post.description }} </p>
        {{ render(controller("ADVCommentBundle:Comment:newComment" ,{ 'id': post.id,'redirect':'get_post' } )) }}
        <hr>
    {%endfor%}
```

CommentController

```
public function newCommentAction (Request $request, Post $post) {
        $em = $this->getEm();
        $comment = new Comment();
        $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType(), $comment);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                try {
                    $em->beginTransaction();
                    $comment->setPost($post);
                    $em->persist($comment);
                    $em->flush();
                    $em->commit();
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $em->rollback();
                    throw $e;
                }
            } 
        return array(
            'post' => $post,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
```

TwifFormController

```
{{ form(form, {'action': path('new_comment',{'id': post.id})})}}
```

When I insert a new comment I have redirect to `new_comment` even if my value isn't valid.
How can I redirect to GeTAllPost and show the correct Error or the new Comment?

I tried to use

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('get_post',array('error',$form->getErrors())));
```

and `'error_bubbling' => true,`, but each time request a get_post ( GetAllPost ) I do a new render of my Form and I don't see the errors

For Example i'd like to use newCommentAction in several scenario. 
For example i GetAllPost for each post, but even in GetSpecificPost, where I Have A specific post, where I Can insert a new comment, but the save ( and the Action ) is the same.

Do I have create a Service ?

**UPDATE**

After Bonswouar's answer. This is my Code
PostController

```
/**
     * @Route("/",name="get_posts")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function getPostsAction () {
        $comment = new Comment();
        return array(
            'commentForms' => $this->createCreateForm($comment),
        );
    }

    private function createCreateForm (Comment $entity) {
        $em = $this->getEm();
        $posts = $em->getRepository('ADVPostBundle:Post')->findAll();
        $commentForms = array();
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType($post->getId()), $entity);
            $commentForms[$post->getId()] = $form->createView();
        }
        return $commentForms;
    }


    /**
     * @Method({"POST"})
     * @Route("/new_comment/{id}",name="new_comment")
     * @Template("@ADVPost/Post/getPosts.html.twig")
     * @ParamConverter("post", class="ADVPostBundle:Post")
     */
    public function newCommentAction (Request $request, Post $post) {
        $em = $this->getEm();
        $comment = new Comment();

        //Sometimes I Have only One Form
        $commentForms = $this->createCreateForm($comment);

        $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType($post->getId()), $comment);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            try {
                $em->beginTransaction();
                $comment->setPost($post);
                $em->persist($comment);
                $em->flush();
                $em->commit();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $em->rollback();
                throw $e;
            }
        } else {
            $commentForms[$post->getId()] = $form->createView();
        }

        return array(
            'commentForms' => $commentForms,
        );
    }
```

And I Don't have any Render.
But, I want to re-use `newCommentAction` also in Single Post, and i Want to create Only one Form. I don't want use `$commentForms = $this->createCreateForm($comment);`,  because i Want just one form,and I have to change template even. How can I do ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your update. I wouldn't do exactly like that.. I updated my answer, is it what you want to do ?

Comment: @Bonswouar thanks again, your answer is a good start for my problem. I'm using your code with some modification. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, your problem is that you're posting on `new_comment`, which is a "sub action".

You actually don't need this Twig `render`.
You could just generate all the forms you need in the main Action, with something like this :

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType($post->getId()), new Comment());
  $form->handleRequest($request);
  if ($form->isValid()) {
    //...
    // Edited : to "empty" the form if submitted & valid. Another option would be to redirect()
    $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType($post->getId()), new Comment());
  }
  $commentForms[$post->getId()] = $form->createView();
}
return array(
  'posts' => $posts,
  'commentForms' => $commentForms,
);
```

Not forgetting to set a dynamic Name in your Form class :

```
class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
     public function __construct($id) {
         $this->postId = $id;
     }
     public function getName() {
         return 'your_form_name'.$this->postId;
     }
     //...
}
```

And then just normally render your forms in your Twig loop. You should get the errors.

```
{% for post in app.user.posts %}
    <p>{{ post.id }} - {{ post.description }} </p>
    {{ form(commentForms[post.id]) }}
    <hr>
{%endfor%}
```

If I didn't miss anything that should do the job.

**UPDATE :**

After seeing your update, this might be the controller you want *(sorry if I didn't understand properly or if I did some mistakes)*:

```
/**
 * @Route("/",name="get_posts")
 * @Template()
 */
public function getPostsAction () {
    $em = $this->getEm();
    $posts = $em->getRepository('ADVPostBundle:Post')->findAll();
    $commentForms = array();
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $commentForms[$post->getId()] = $this->createCommentForm($post);
    }
    return array(
        'commentForms' => $commentForms
    );
}

private function createCommentForm (Post $post, $request = null) {
    $em = $this->getEm();
    $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType($post->getId()), new Comment());
    if ($request) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            try {
                $em->beginTransaction();
                $comment->setPost($post);
                $em->persist($comment);
                $em->flush();
                $em->commit();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $em->rollback();
                throw $e;
            }
            $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType($post->getId()), new Comment());
        }
    }
    return $form;
}


/**
 * @Method({"POST"})
 * @Route("/new_comment/{id}",name="new_comment")
 * @Template("@ADVPost/Post/getPosts.html.twig")
 * @ParamConverter("post", class="ADVPostBundle:Post")
 */
public function newCommentAction (Request $request, Post $post) {
    return array(
        'commentForm' => $this->createCommentForm($post, $request);
    );
}
```

Comment: I think this is much cleaner than my solution and makes more sense, nice job.

Comment: thanks, nice solution. One Question. If I have another Action like "SpecificPost", where I have Only one post, I have to create the new logic (`if ($form->isValid())` etc etc ). Then I will have two action very similar. One for AllPost, and one for Specific Post. With twig render I'd like to have only one Action, but share in both scenario

Comment: Only one problem, When i Reload the page I find form pre-populated with last comment

Comment: About the duplicate logic, you could factorize it in a Service, or "easier" just make a method in your Controller that you'll use for both Actions.
And about your problem after reloading the page, it's probably because you're using the populated valid object (`new Comment()` is not new anymore after you handled the request), instead of that you could use a new one at the end of your `isValid` logic.

Comment: @Bonswouar if i Put `$commentForms[$post->getId()] = $form->createView();` before `$form->handleRequest($request);` I Don't see the previous comment, but if i have an error, i Don't see it in Browser

Comment: You don't see the error in the browser ? You should check your apache/php configuration. Anyway, I didn't mean to do the `createView()` before, but doing another `createForm()` after. I just edited my Answer. EDIT : If you don't like this (twice the same line, not so great) you could also `redirect` if valid instead.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a flash message to set your error messages?  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#flash-messages

**EDIT:** Modifying based on your comments.  In your controller you could do this:

```
foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
    $this->addFlash('error', $post->getId().'|'.$error->getMessage());
}
```

or

```
$this->addFlash('error',  $post->getId().'|'.(string) $form->getErrors(true, false));
```

What this will do is allow you to tie the error to the particular post you want, as you are passing it a string like *355|This value is already used*. If you need to know the field you could add another delimiter for *$error->getPropertyPath()* in your flash message, or you could overwrite the error name in the entity itself.

Then in your controller you could parse out the flash messages, and add them to an array that your twig template would check:

```
$errors = array();

foreach ($this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->get('error', array()) as $error)
{
    list($postId, $message) = explode('|', $error);

    $errors[$postId][] = $message;
}

return array('errors' => $errors, ...anything else you send to the template)
```

Now your twig template can check for the existence of errors on that particular form:

```
{% for post in app.user.posts %}
    {% if errors[post.id] is defined %}
        <ul class="errors">
        {% for error_message in errors[post.id] %}
            <li>{{ error_message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    <p>{{ post.id }} - {{ post.description }} </p>
    {{ render(controller("ADVCommentBundle:Comment:newComment" ,{ 'id': post.id,'redirect':'get_post' } )) }}
    <hr>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried with FlashMessage, and works but not well. Because, if i Insert a new comment to 10th Form in the global Page, my error appears in top of page.

Comment: Anyway for use FlashMEssage, I have To use `'error_bubbling' => true` and redirect in my `newCommentAction...I have `UniqueEntity: comment` and The message that I retrieve is `This value is already used. which field? of which form?